# Ember.js cannot set content of ArrayController

Tags: javascript, ember.js, javascript-framework

Suppose I have an `ArrayController`:

```
CellarRails.SearchController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: []
});
```

and a `SearchRoute`:

```
CellarRails.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log('MODEL HOOKED!!');
    return CellarRails.Track.find(params);
  }
});
```

and a find method in model:

```
CellarRails.Track.reopenClass({
  find: function(params) {
    ...
    some code
    ...
    return result;
  }
});
```

**PROBLEM:** The result array is returning properly, model hook is fired, but content of controller is undefined and it's length is 0, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the `setupController` hook and setting the content to the model returned by your `find()` operation:

```
CellarRails.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log('MODEL HOOKED!!');
    return CellarRails.Track.find(params);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

### Update, in response to your last comment

See [here](http://jsbin.com/odosoy/47/edit) for a working demo.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But `model` hook should set content of controller in the context of `searchRoute`, isn't it? Anyway `{{controller.content.length}}` in my `search` template shows **0**, but length of `result` arays is **50**. P.S. I'm not using ember-params anymore :)

Comment: @Nikita, added demo to my answer, it works in the example, can you compare it to your code what might be different?